# PHP if statement display always the same

Tags: php, if-statement

Short question what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
if ($arrItem['text']['kachelband_de_external_link'] = "1"){
    echo 'target="_blank"';
} else{

}
?>
```

I always get the output: `target="_blank"`, even `if "$arrItem['text']['kachelband_de_external_link']" = 0`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing an assignment operation instead of comparison on your `if` statement.

Should be

```
if ($arrItem['text']['kachelband_de_external_link'] == "1")
```

*See the two equal signs ?*

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($arrItem['text']['kachelband_de_external_link'] == "1"){
    echo 'target="_blank"';
    }
```

use `==` to check conditions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
if ($arrItem['text']['kachelband_de_external_link'] == "1")
```

and not only one of "=". If you only use one, you set the var before. By using 2 "=" you compare ;)